# await does not affect async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, spotify

Hi i'm fairly new to javascript and I'm having a problem with my async function inside the AddEventListener method that is not awaiting the fetch result, so when i try to `console.log(track_info.tracks)` it prints out `undefined`.

```js
const getTrack = async (urlTrack) => {
  const result = await fetch(urlTrack, {          
    method: "GET",
    headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("access_token")}
  });
  
  const data = await result.json();
  return data;
}

songBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  var searchSongBar = document.getElementById('search_song').value; //gets string from searchbar
  sessionStorage.setItem("title", searchSongBar); //saves the string as title in sessionStorage
       
  const trackTitle = sessionStorage.getItem('title'); //takes title and puts it inside the variable to use in the url
  var urlTrack = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${trackTitle}&type=track&market=us&limit=1&include_external=false`;
  var track_info = getTrack(urlTrack);
  console.log(track_info.tracks)
});
```

Comment: `var track_info = getTrack(urlTrack);` You're missing an await here. `var track_info = await getTrack(urlTrack);` getTrack returns a promise (async functions always return promises)

Comment: you need to know that `async` functions returning an promise and it needs to be awaited aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

You need to add an `await` to the call of getTrack. `var track_info = await getTrack(urlTrack);`

#### Helpful Tips

[How to await fetch](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/) You do not need to `await` both fetch and result.json as you are awaiting an already returned result. You can `await` result.json, however awaiting fetch in this instance is not needed since fetch is returning a promise.

[How to await promises](https://javascript.info/async-await) You created an asynchronous function, and just like fetch, you need to await the result before continuing. A good rule of thumb is that you should await an asynchronous function whenever you need to reference the data returned. You awaited fetch() so you could access result.json(). Likewise, you await getTrack() so you can console.log its return value.

```
const getTrack = async (urlTrack) => {

    const result = await fetch(urlTrack, {          
        method: "GET",
        headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + 
            localStorage.getItem("access_token")}
    });

    return result.json();
}


      

songBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    var searchSongBar = document.getElementById('search_song').value; //gets string from searchbar
    sessionStorage.setItem("title", searchSongBar); //saves the string as title in sessionStorage
    const trackTitle = sessionStorage.getItem('title'); //takes title and puts it inside the variable to use in the url
    var urlTrack = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${trackTitle}&type=track&market=us&limit=1&include_external=false`;

    var track_info = await getTrack(urlTrack);
    console.log(track_info.tracks);
});
```